# HTTP_PRAGMA : no-cache,HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL : no-cache

Tags: php, caching

Hi We have two server on which running Apache 2.4.10 on windows when we compare phpinfo() on two servers one server is showing following extra properties. Even though both have same apache and php configurations.

```
<tr><td class="e">HTTP_PRAGMA </td><td class="v">no-cache </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL </td><td class="v">no-cache </td></tr>

 phpinfo();
```

We are facing one functional issue and we suspect that this issue is due to this. But no luck to find the root cause though. The functionality is to generate pdf using third party php utility. The pdf is generated however images in pdf are messed up. one image is replacing all three images.(If there are 3 different images image 1 is displayed at all three locations.)

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: These HTTP Header values can be controlled over html, php, and .htaccess too. Check all of them. I don't know why your images was messed up in the pdf, but I also don't know what library do you use. I've used TCPDF for a long time for generating PDF documents, but never had this kind of problem.

Comment: we are using PHPDocX utility weird thing is on one environment it is running fine without any issue. both the environments are running same version of php and apache. even we compared configs both are same. so no clue how it is behaving differently.